# Problem in importing data

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a file including some data. When I want to check to be even or not to be even of data, my code does not work. But when I check apart from the data file, it works. I don't know why my code does not work. How can I solve the problem of the code?

It's a great pleasure if you help me.

My data file can be downloaded from [here](https://ufile.io/z6oq6)

Here is my code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
d = Flatten[Import["the file path in your computer","Data"]];
data = Partition[d, 5];
t = data[[2, 1]]
EvenQ[t]
EvenQ[52]
```

The results are

```
52.

False

True
```

Comment: `EvenQ[52.] != EvenQ[52]`

Comment: See [`EvenQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvenQ.html) - the argument **must** be an `Integer`.  Use `Round` to convert `52.` into an integer.

Comment: Dear Jason B. If I use round, the precision of the data will change. I don't want to lose the precision.

Comment: How you choose to get around the issue is up to you, but you just can't feed a non-integer to `EvenQ` and get back `True`

Comment: Use `Mod[t, 2] == 0` then. See linked topic and topics linked there.

Comment: Thanks, dear Jason B.

Comment: Dear  Kuba, I need to use Mathematica commands.

Comment: @HadiSobhani and?

Comment: I need to come up with an idea which enables Mathematica treats with those data as an integer.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem with `Mod[t, 2] == 0` if you can not use `EvenQ` on real numbers and are refusing to convert your real numbers to integers with `Round`. p.s. use @Kuba, otherwise I won't get notified.

Comment: Dear @Kuba, I want to make a change on imported data such that I will be able to use     EvenQ    command. I believe that your recommendation about  using     Mod[t, 2] == 0  is right.